# Creating a LightInject Bootstrapper for Prism, missing registration of region adapters

Tags: c#, prism, prism-6, light-inject

I'm trying to create a LightInject bootstrapper for Prism, I've copied the code of the `NinjectBootstrapper` ([source](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/a60d38013c02b60807e9287db9ba7f7506af0e84/Source/Wpf/Prism.Ninject.Wpf/NinjectBootstrapper.cs)) and replaced Ninject's `IKernel` with LightInject's `IServiceContainer`. I've also created and registered a `LightInjectServiceLocatorAdapter` ([Ninject version](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/a60d38013c02b60807e9287db9ba7f7506af0e84/Source/Wpf/Prism.Ninject.Wpf/NinjectServiceLocatorAdapter.cs)).

The registration and service locator adapter are working. I see that the class `RegionAdapterMappings` is successfully retrieved from the service locator.

In the `ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings` step of the bootstrapper an instance of the class `SelectorRegionAdapter` is requested from the service locator. This fails. The class was never registered. I can't find any reference to it in the `NinjectBootstrapper`. So how is this class retrieved by the Ninject bootstrapper?

I've tried registering the class manually (and a few more region adapters and the `DelayedRegionCreationBehavior`) but then Prism fails with an `UpdateRegionsException`

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Prism.Regions.Behaviors.RegionCreationException: An exception occurred while creating a region with name 'Menu'. The exception was: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The IRegionAdapter for the type System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl is not registered in the region adapter mappings. You can register an IRegionAdapter for this control by overriding the ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings method in the bootstrapper.
```

I can't find any source dealing with creating adding your own DI container and I have no idea what step I am missing. What am I doing wrong?

I configure my `ServiceContainer` like this (the Ninject equivalent is the `ConfigureKernel` method).

```
protected virtual void ConfigureServiceContainer()
{
    this.ServiceContainer.RegisterInstance<IServiceContainer>(this.ServiceContainer);
    this.ServiceContainer.RegisterInstance(this.Logger);
    this.ServiceContainer.RegisterInstance(this.ModuleCatalog);

    if (!this.useDefaultConfiguration)
        return;

    this.ServiceContainer.Register<IServiceLocator, LightInjectServiceLocatorAdapter>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<IModuleInitializer, ModuleInitializer>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<IModuleManager, ModuleManager>();

    this.ServiceContainer.Register<RegionAdapterMappings, RegionAdapterMappings>();

    // The following 4 registrations are not in the NinjectBootstrapper
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<SelectorRegionAdapter, SelectorRegionAdapter>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<ItemsControlRegionAdapter, ItemsControlRegionAdapter>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<ContentControlRegionAdapter, ContentControlRegionAdapter>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<DelayedRegionCreationBehavior, DelayedRegionCreationBehavior>();

    this.ServiceContainer.Register<IRegionManager, RegionManager>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<IRegionViewRegistry, RegionViewRegistry>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<IRegionBehaviorFactory, RegionBehaviorFactory>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<IRegionNavigationJournalEntry, RegionNavigationJournalEntry>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<IRegionNavigationJournal, RegionNavigationJournal>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<IRegionNavigationService, RegionNavigationService>();
    this.ServiceContainer.Register<IRegionNavigationContentLoader, RegionNavigationContentLoader>();
}
```

Comment: I see two close votes, but I don't understand the reason why? Any comments on that?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there were two things that I did wrong.

For the registration in `ConfigureServiceContainer` the Ninject bootstrapper uses an extension method `public static void RegisterTypeIfMissing<A, B>(this IServiceContainer container, bool singletonScope)` that registers some of the dependencies in singleton scope.

The other thing I didn't understand is that Ninject will happily resolve any concrete type even if it isn't registered. LightInject does not. I finally solved this by registering all the concrete classes from Prism.WPF that end in "Behavior" or "Adapter" to themselves like this:

```
// Register all concrete adapters and behaviors in the Prism.WPF assembly
var wpfAssembly = typeof (SelectorRegionAdapter).Assembly;
this.ServiceContainer.RegisterAssembly(wpfAssembly, (t0, t1) => t0.Name.EndsWith("Adapter") || t0.Name.EndsWith("Behavior"));
```

Finally I had to ditch all the Module management from Prism. LightInject expects a single class that extends from `ICompositionRoot` to be present in an assembly and will load types happily from there. This works fine for my approach :).